# JS / CSS Horizontal mousewheel scrolling website bugs out in safari

Tags: javascript, css

could you please help me out with the following problem?

context:

Let me start of saying I'm a amateur / hobbyist webdesigner, far from anything professional. I've been busy making a website for my business. The portfolio section contains a horizontal mousewheel scrolling section, so the images read from left to right.
I have made the website with muse, and implemented some custom CSS and JS code in there to make the horizontal scrolling happen. my knowledge of JS is limited.

problem:

Everything works fine, except in safari. Here the horizontal scrolling doesn't work. This has to do with overflow-y:hidden I have set at html and body. If I remove this, the scrolling works in safari BUT without the overflow-y: hidden, the website will not show properly in responsive mode as it will exceed the content height, showing a big blank space underneath the content where the user can swipe down to. I tried a lot of things but unfortunately I feel I'm at a dead end. Could anyone please help me out?

goal:

- desktop mode: allow horizontal mousewheel scrolling in safari
- responsive mode: don't show big empty space beneath content

website URL:
http://www.jellevdvegt.nl/kam.html

Comment: Try setting `overflow-x: auto;` too.

Comment: doesn't work :( the scrollbar in x direction is active but the mousewheelscrolling bugs out.